# Improve Algorithm Java

Tags: java, performance, function, optimization

I have thought of a function that takes as input a message of type String (ex: "hello") and checks in a sea of random letters of type String (ex: "sdgjkahjkdghkjsaeasdflasfdo") if the letters exist such that the message can be reconstructed.

My question is whether and how can I improve this algorithm to be more efficient.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String letters = "asfhgsaihgaojmbpapojtnmaiuwbqapweqfbsjadsheeadsaslasfaslasasopz";

    String message ="helloc";

    System.out.println(seaOfLetters(message, letters));

}

public static boolean check(char[] a, char[] b) {
    CHECK: for (int i = 0; i < a.length ; ++i) {
        if (a[i] == b[i]) {
            continue CHECK;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean seaOfLetters(String m, String l) {

    char[] message = m.toCharArray();
    char[] letters = l.toCharArray();

    char[] newchar = new char[message.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < message.length ; i++) {
        CHECK: for (int j = 0; j < l.length() ; j++) {
            if (message[i] == letters[j]) {
                newchar[i] = message[i];
                break CHECK;
            }

        }
    }

    return check(message, newchar);
```

Comment: If the "sea of letters" has a constant length, so Big-O is _O(n)_, with `n` being the length of the message. Otherwise it is _O(nm)_, with `m` being the length of the "sea".

Comment: If this code works fine, then this question is off topic on Stack Overflow.  It may be good for our sister site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but please remember to check [their rules](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting.

Comment: Your code seems to be a very convoluted way to check if all characters in the message are present in the "sea of letters". A better way would be to add the letters of the sea to a `Set<Character>`, then check the characters of the message against that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code works.  Code Review is a more appropriate Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Andreas, if you add all the letters in a ``Set`` then for input : ``letters = 
 "d"``  and ``message = "dddddd"`` your solution will work, which is not correct

Comment: Improvement: start by removing any label from your code. That was used in the 80s...

Comment: @SchiduLuca Why is that not correct? It gives same result as your code. Besides, that's exactly what the accepted answer also suggested in the last paragraph, so if it is not correct, why did you accept it?

Comment: @Andreas, what code? I didn't write any

Comment: @SchiduLuca Sorry, thought you were the OP. Doesn't change my question to you: Why is my suggestion not correct, in your opinion?

Comment: @Andreas, you have also to keep track of occurrences of chars in letters String.  If your letters String contains a single "d" for example, and your message contains 4 "d" ,  you can't  reconstruct message of 4 d's from a single d from letters

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner guava's `CharMatcher#removeFrom` has a `label25` :) for at least 3 years now... I did some testing around with `JMH` to prove that the implementation is, well, an under-implementation, but no one cares :)

Comment: @Eugene will surely look into that, guava + label... They surely have a reason to use it, but...

Comment: @SchiduLuca Nothing in the question says that, and the code surely doesn't work that way, and the question is requesting better *efficiency*, implicitly saying that the code is working as intended. What you are saying makes sense *(sea of letters not making a lot of sense otherwise)*, but that seems to be for a different problem, not the problem of this question, given the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49466583/5221149), and the [comment OP left there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49466449/improve-algorithm-java?noredirect=1#comment85940542_49466583).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can analyze the algorithm to see how many operations it has to do in best/worst cases to try to get a sense of the complexity.

You could also try running it for a series of values and time it. Set something up that starts a timer right before the algorithm starts, and outputs the time passed once it finishes. You could then run this for increasing sizes of sets and see how the time changes, then plot it. Make sure to run over several orders of magnitude (1, 10, 100, 1000, etc) for both the "sea" and "message" to get a sense of what really drives the complexity.

To improve the algorithm, you could consider using a HashSet. These have O(1) complexity for "contains" checks. So your program would basically have two steps, 1. add everything of "sea" to a HashSet, then 2. iterate over the "message" and see if the letters are in the set.

Comment: Tried it with the HashSet. It's impressively fast. Constant time vs log time wins. For a "sea of letters" full of duplicates, the HashSet is very efficient. The process time for a message "helloc" (appended a million times) to be reconstructed from a sea of millions of random letters is of 38 milliseconds with the HashSet whereas for the original function the process time took slightly over 3 minutes. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array in the length of the alphabet.

1. Run through your message and for each letter update the letter count, as well as the total letters count.
2. Run through the "sea" and for each letter that you found that is contained in the original message, decrement the appropriate counter, and the total counter.
3. Finish when the total counter is 0, or the "sea" is finished.

O(n+m) worst case.

Answer (score 0):

With a regular expression, you can easily remove all letters not in your target from the source, which gives you a much simpler text to parse:

```
letters.replaceAll ("[^"+message+"]", "")
"hhooeheello"
```

Now you still have to check for the right count of characters (two 
'l') and the right order. How fast it is, I haven't tested, but I guess this first step is pretty fast.